# Customize XML comments in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, documentation, comments

In VS2008 just before a method if you add “///” it automatically adds the summary block…
Do you know if it is possible to modify the default to this?

```
/// <summary>
/// Author : Failboy
/// </summary>
```

I would like it to have my in by default – without having to add it every time

Comment: Do you want that on types, fields and methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in here.

[Customizing XML Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx#id0400027)

Answer (score 4):

Use [Ghost Doc](http://submain.com/ghostdoc/). It supports customising these. Most importantly it saves the tonne of other info you need to type in.

Comment: thanks for the link (+1) but I'm accepting kevchadders answer because its not a download thats required.